# Repeated output in simple for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I've got the following list

```
ninjas = ['ryu', 'crystal', 'yoshi', 'ken']
```

I'm playing around with loops and have the following for loop

```
for ninja in ninjas:
    if ninja == 'ryu':
        print(f'{ninja} - black belt')
    if ninja == 'ken':
        print(f'{ninja} - brown belt')
    else:
        print(ninja)
```

The output I want is

```
ryu - black belt
crystal
yoshi
ken - brown belt
```

but the output I get is

```
ryu - black belt
ryu
crystal
yoshi
ken - brown belt
```

I'm assuming that after the first if statement it is looping back around to the start, hence the repeated 'ryu', how do I stop it doing that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *I'm assuming that after the first if statement it is looping back around to the start* that is false, it continues to the next if statement which has an else condition. You need to nest your ifs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get what you actually expect you need:

```
for ninja in ninjas:
    if ninja == 'ryu':
        print(f'{ninja} - black belt')
    elif ninja == 'ken':
        print(f'{ninja} - brown belt')
    else:
        print(ninja)
```

Comment: Thank you, I had just figured out another way to do it seconds after you posted but yours is more concise so I much prefer it.